# How to run a focused functional test in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rake

In users_controller_test.rb I have:

```
def test_name 
  ...
end

def test_name_2 
  ...
end

etc...
```

Is it possible to run only the first test from the command line? Something like:

```
 rake test:functionals TEST=test/functional/users_controller_test.rb (plus the test name?)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

`ruby test/functional/users_controller_test.rb -n test_name`

Comment: I'm getting `require: no such file to load -- test/functional/../test_helper (LoadError)` when I try the above

Answer (score 0):

You might get some traction from
ruby test/functional/users_controller_test.rb --something